# Service with multiple ports/protocols per route (e.g. HTTP and HTTPS) possible in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I am currently evaluating OpenShift for use in our company. 
We have a web application in a container, which exposes both port 80 http and port 443 https. Is it possible to run this container in OpenShift, using both ports over the SAME hostname? The OpenShift GUI lets me select only one port per service, if I try to create a route, and either http or https, not both. My use-case is, that my application is reachable on http://my-app as well as on https://my-app (in my opinion a quite common use-case)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have multiple routes with the same hostname and path. Only first such route will be admitted to the router.
The routes with paths will work as mentioned by @Graham

You can put all 3 below in a single project without problem:

- example.com
- example.com/hello
- example.com/world

They can have different protocols. Adding a duplicate route with different protocol will not work.

Additionally if you have Project B, you won't be able to use example.com host again. So, none of the below will be accepted to a router:

- example.com
- example.com/hello
- example.com/world
- example.com/path

Which makes sense, as you don't want someone else to use your domain.

What usually happens when you have https exposed is that all http traffic is redirected to https. 
You can achieve it by creating edge terminated route (over UI) and selecting Insecure Traffic: Redirect. There is also an option to set it to Allow. 
More documentation and yaml examples if you would like to create route from command line: [OpenShift Origin: Secured routes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#secured-routes)

Comment: This answer is confusing in its first paragraph. You can have both HTTP and HTTPS traffic terminated for the same hostname. You even state as much in the second paragraph, which is what they are asking about. It is also possible to have multiple HTTP or HTTPS routes for the same hostname for the specific case where one is for whole site, and others are at a sub URL path overlaid on one for whole site.